# How to connect android project with Infermedica API?

Tags: android, api, medical

Im currently working on a symptom based disease prediction project but I got stuck up in how to  connect my android project with Infermedica API and send the symptoms and get the results?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Android Asynchronous Http. For details go to  http://loopj.com/android-async-http/

In general, it works this way.

```
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    String url = yourUrl
    client.get(this, url, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
            if (statusCode ==200){
                //Status 200 == Everything worked fine, responseBody has the content.;

                }
            }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
            Toast.makeText(Activity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    });
```

And you must import the library in your gradle.

```
compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
```

The above example is for GET petition, if you want POST, you have to change it and add params to the function. You can check that on the previous link.